# My trigger is running forever? Any idea why?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have created the follow TSQL trigger that appears to be running forever whenever the underlying table gets updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Trigger_MDSS_ComputeAggregates
ON dbo.MonthlyDetectionScoresSums
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS
BEGIN


update dbo.MonthlyDetectionScoresSums
SET
YPElec = CAST(COALESCE (i.YPLocChain_TotElec, i.YPGlobChain_TotElec, i.YPSIC_TotElec) AS real),
YPGas = CAST(COALESCE (i.YPLocChain_TotGas, i.YPSIC_TotGas) AS real)
from MonthlyDetectionScoresSums mdss
inner join INSERTED i on i.ACI_OI = mdss.ACI_OI

END
GO
```

Do you know why it might be running for a really really long time?

Comment: How many rows are in the `MonthlyDetectionScoresSums` table?

Comment: Between 500K and 5 million rows depending on the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have recursive triggers turned on?

Although an infinite loop should be terminated, it's possible if your update is very large that it takes a long time to get to the nesting limit of 32:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190739.aspx

Comment: Hmm... I just changed this to disable nesting and it doesn't appear to have worked. Good idea though.

Comment: He had originally thought it did work and then apparently didn't clear the flag when he discovered it didn't work after all.

Comment: Actually, I went back and forth. Turned out I had recursion on and there was something in the system that was kicking off a complete table update every 10 seconds so it was throwing me off a bit. This was the right solution after all.

Comment: Cool!  Glad it was useful!  gbn's answer below is definitely how you want to structure things if you can, though.

Answer (score 5):

May I suggest that you use [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186241.aspx) and drop the trigger?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MonthlyDetectionScoresSums ADD
    YPElec AS CAST(COALESCE (YPLocChain_TotElec, YPGlobChain_TotElec, YPSIC_TotElec) AS real)
    YPGas AS CAST(COALESCE (YPLocChain_TotGas, YPSIC_TotGas) AS real)
```

From what I see, you are updating rows you've just updated/inserted. The DB engine will do it for you and no trigger needed.

Comment: This is the right solution for sure. I'm going to change them to use this from now on.